# Every projective $R$-module $P$ is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

I have come across a theorem which states that if the underlying ring $R$ is a principal ideal domain then every $R$-module $P$ which is projective is free also.

But the problem is I have encountered the example of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_6$ which is  projective  but not free. But $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is a PID.

Then how is the theorem true?

Comment: Free but not projective is not the same as projective but not free.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is not a PID, because it's not a domain.

Comment: Yes $ [3][2]=[0]$ ;I missed that